# QT live video streaming on ARM Linux

Tags: qt, streaming, rtsp, rtp, live555

I am working on a system that includes two units: control unit and display unit both are ARM linux boards.I want to choose videos from sd card or usb on the control unit and stream this video to display unit and lastly show live video on display unit.I searched web and learned RTP and RTSP protocols can be using for this system.Several applications created with LibVLC and Live555 libs.But I need a clear example to   simply work this system on Qt enviroment(developing on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS).Most important point is; I need any guy's experiments on this app which one is stable and good performance (FPS).I appriciate you to helping me with this problem.

Thanks.